# LeetCode: Set Matrix zero

Tags: python-3.x, math, matrix

LOGIC: For every place where we have to insert a zero, we put a None besides the places that are already 0. This way we keep track of our zeroes and update the matrix inplace. And in the end we replace all of Nones with zeroes.
Question:
Why is my code not able to remove None from all the places in the matrix. It only removes from a few places.

```
class Solution:
    def setZeroes(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
        """
        
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
                if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                    for t in range(len(matrix[0])):
                        if matrix[i][t] != 0:
                            matrix[i][t] = None
                    
                    for k in range(len(matrix)):
                        if matrix[k][j] != 0:
                            matrix[k][j] = None
       
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix)):
                if matrix[i][j] == None:
                    matrix[i][j] = 0
```

See image for result output:

[image]

Please help as I am surprised to not see it work.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the first set of loops:

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
```

To the second:

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
```

See the difference?

Comment: I am a legend to not be able to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

Brute Force in Python:

```py
def setZeros(matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    temp=[]
    m=len(matrix)
    n=len(matrix[0])
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if matrix[i][j]==0:
                temp.append([i,j])
    for i,j in temp:
        for a in range(n):
            matrix[i][a]=0
        for b in range(m):
            matrix[b][j]=0
    return matrix
#Time complexity:O(N^2) +O(N^3)
#space complexity:O(2*N)
```

Optimised Approach in Python:

```py
class Solution:
    def setZeroes(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
        m=len(matrix)
        n=len(matrix[0])
        iszerorow=False
        iszerocol=False
        for i in range(n):# for first row
            if matrix[0][i]==0:
                iszerorow=True
        for i in range(m):# for first column
            if matrix[i][0]==0:
                iszerocol=True
        for i in range(1,m):
            for j in range(1,n):
                if matrix[i][j]==0:
                    matrix[0][j]=0# make first row zero
                    matrix[i][0]=0 # make first column zero
        for i in range(1,m):
            for j in range(1,n):
                if matrix[i][0]==0 or matrix[0][j]==0:# now make zero on respective row and column
                    matrix[i][j]=0
        if iszerorow==True:
            for i in range(n): # make for first row
                matrix[0][i]=0
        if iszerocol==True:
            for i in range(m):# make for first column
                matrix[i][0]=0
    
#Time complexity:O(N)+O(m)+O(N^2)+O(N^2)+O(N)+O(M)=O(N^2)
#space complexity:O(1)
```